# C# System.Drawing.Bitmap throwing Out of Memory Exception when cloning

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I have a Bitmap image which I am trying to clone as below:

```
Bitmap bmpCrop = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(left, top, right - left + 1, bottom - top), bmp.PixelFormat);
```

Sometimes this line throws an exception of type OutOfMemoryException so previously to clone I want to be sure that the coordinates specified in the Rectangle are not outside the bounds of the bitmap since as far as I know, Clone() may also throw an Out of memory exception.

I know I can get the bounds of the image by doing:

```
GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Point;
RectangleF bmpRectangleF = bmp.GetBounds(ref units);
```

but then I do not know how to comprare with Rectanble bounds.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: bmpRectangleF.Contains() can test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have done below (thanks to Alex K. for the suggestion):

```
RectangleF rectangleF = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(left, top, right - left + 1, bottom - top);
GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
RectangleF bmpRectangleF = bmp.GetBounds(ref units);
if (bmpRectangleF.Contains(rectangleF))
{
    Bitmap bmpCrop = bmp.Clone(rectangleF, bmp.PixelFormat);
    return (Bitmap)(bmpCrop);
}
```